# How to write a regex for a decimal number scenario with a specific range?

Tags: angular, regex

I am trying to write a Regex that satisfies the below criteria.
I tried below one though few of my criteria doesnt match with the below regex.

```
^([0-9]{1,2})(\.0)|(\.[1-9]{1,2})$
```

1. A decimal number that is of nn.mm (nn,mm can be numbers [0-9])
2. If mm is present for example if 01,02,03..09, then the second is not allowed, because first number is 0.

Valid values are `10.00, 10.10,99.12, 12.99, 10.11, 01.10, 00.00, 00.10, 1.1, 0.9, 0.1, 2.3, 1.10, 9.20, 4.56 ....

Invalid values are `00.01, 99.01, 12.09, 10.08, 10.01, 10.02...10.09` (because after decimal point, first digit is 0 which is invalid)

TO be more precise:

```
[0-9][0-9].0  //valid
[0-9][0-9].[0-9]0  //valid
[0-9].0  //valid
[0-9].[0-9]0  //valid
[0-9][0-9].[0-9]0 //valid

[0-9].0[0-9] //invalid
[0-9][0-9].0[0-9] //invalid
```

Comment: Did you miss the outer brackets? `^(([0-9]{1,2})(\.0)|(\.[1-9]{1,2}))$`

Comment: Its not about missing the brackets, but the Regex itself doenot satisfy my requirement

Comment: What about `[0-9].[0-9]`?

Comment: And it appears (for example) `21.4` is not valid?

Comment: It seems the last line `[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]` makes 99.12 and 12.99 invalid, although you say they are valid numbers

Comment: I am sorry but i have updated the valid and invalid values. So with this regex ^[0-9]{1,2}\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$   ==>  - how to make nn.00, also as valid in this regex, for example, 00.00, 10.00, 20.00, 01.00, 99.00, 23.00, 45.00........because the regex doesnt accept these two scenarios

Comment: See https://tools.waytolearnx.com/en/regex-tester/eab73c7c30e3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should give you the results you want:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}\.(?:00?|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

It matches:

- `^` : beginning of string
- `[0-9]{1,2}` : 1 or 2 digits
- `\.` : a period (`.`)
- `(?:00?|[1-9][0-9]?)` : either:

  - `00?` : a zero, followed by an optional 0; or
  - `[1-9][0-9]?` : a digit in the range `1-9`, followed by an optional second digit
- `$` : end of string

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Fur9NE/1)

Comment: Thanks, just had to do a small correction on top of your regEx, ^[0-9]{1,2}\.(?:00|[1-9][0-9])$

Comment: @Nancy ah, I wasn't sure from your question whether you were allowed only 1 digit before the decimal point. Your words and sample data all had 2... you might want to edit the question to reflect that one is allowed.

Comment: Also it should accept, n.n ==> n can be from [0-9]

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I am sorry but i have updated the valid and invalid values. So with this regex ^[0-9]{1,2}\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$ ==> - how to make nn.00, also as valid in this regex, for example, 00.00, 10.00, 20.00, 01.00, 99.00, 23.00, 45.00........because the regex doesnt accept these two scenarios

Comment: Hi Nancy, have you tried the regex in my most recent edit? I believe it works for all your requirements: https://regex101.com/r/Fur9NE/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *match pattern*.

```
^\d\d\.(?:00|[1-9]\d|\d)$
```